# VBA machine info and/or drivers available

Tags: excel, connection-string, ms-jet-ace, vba

We have some code in VBA that uses a connection string to open an MDB.

We have found that the connection string has to change depending on the machine - it *seems* that .Jet.4 is no longer available on modern OS's (?) and that we need to use ACE.12 instead. But other machines support Jet.4 fine.

Great, so how do we write VBA that knows which string to use? Is there a way to get a list of installed drivers, or some other solution to this problem?